# How is the output of the below C program equal to 3?

Tags: c

I was doing some programming problems and I ran into the below snippet

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d", 1 ^ 0 + 3 ^ 0 == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The output to this code is 3 somehow, please help me understand how this is.

My thought process: 1^0 = 1, 3^0 = 3 then 1 + 3 = 4 which is not equal to 0 so the result should be zero.

Comment: Operator precedence!  Which has higher precedence — `^` or `+`?

Comment: Please turn up the compiler warnings. MS VC says *warning C4554: '^': check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence*. And you may be interested in [Precedence and order of evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and `==` for that matter

Comment: @JeffMercado — yup, that (`==`) too.

Comment: Help yourself in 6 months time and do not use that kind of expressions. If you must use the expressions (ab)use parenthesis to reflect exactly what you are thinking: `printf("%d\n", ((1 ^ 0) + (3 ^ 0)) == 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ted Lyngmo is correct to point you to the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) table. A relevant clipping of it. *Top to bottom in order of decreasing precedence.*

| Level | Operator |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | () |
| 4 | + |
| 7 | == |
| 9 | ^ |

Consequently, if we disambiguate your expression with parentheses:

```
1 ^ 0 + 3 ^ 0 == 0 

1 ^ (0 + 3) ^ 0 == 0

1 ^ (0 + 3) ^ (0 == 0)

(1 ^ (0 + 3)) ^ (0 == 0)
```

If we begin simplifying this:

```
(1 ^ (0 + 3)) ^ 1

(1 ^ 3) ^ 1

(0b01 ^ 0b11) ^ 0b01

0b10 ^ 0b01

0b11

3
```

Answer (score 5):

[Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and this example may help:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", 1 ^ (0 + 3) ^ (0 == 0));
}
```

Comment: I wonder if all of the `printf` calls just add noise and this might be better formatted as a table with the subexpressions and what they evaluate to.

Comment: @Chris I agree. I would make it into a proper table if time permitted. I removed the noise for now. Will add table later.

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Representation**

The answers provided already explain the reasoning behind the posed behavior pretty well, but a more visual description of the way the equation is simplified by C might be helpful for future visitors -:

```
1 ^ 0 + 3 ^ 0 == 0
1 ^ (0 + 3) ^ 0 == 0
1 ^ 3 ^ (0 == 0)
(1 ^ 3) ^ 1
2 ^ 1
3
```

---

**Operator Precedence**

The equation has been solved based on the following [operator predence order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) -:

[image: C operator predence]

---

**EXPLANATION:**

The given equation is solved by C based on it's operator precedence rules listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). For the operators used in the given equation, the precedence order is as follows -:

> (+) > (==) > (^)

Furthermore, if all the operators in the equation, are of equal precedence, then the equation is solved from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to precedence:

The plus(+) operator has precedence over comparison (==) operator,
and comparison (==) has precedence over XOR(^) operator.  Please see the comments and code below:

Runnable code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Yo414q3ze)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    /* Plus(+) operator has precedence over comparison (==) operator,
    ** and comparison (==) has precedence over XOR(^) operator, so 
    ** evaluation goes like so:
    ** 1 ^ 0 + 3 ^ 0 == 0
    ** 1 ^ (0 + 3) ^ 0 == 0 
    ** 1 ^ 3 ^ (0 == 0)
    ** 1 ^ 3 ^ 1       <-- so this should print 3.  */
    printf("%d\n", 1 ^ 3 ^ 1);  /* Prints '3' ? -- yup */
    
    /* When you want to be sure about precedence and 
    ** what is going on, you can always de-obfuscate 
    ** by forcing precedence with parenthesis */
    printf("%d\n", ((1 ^ 0) + (3 ^ 0)) == 0 );  /* Prints '0' */

    printf("%d\n", ((1 ^ 0) + (3 ^ 0)));    /* Prints '4' */

    return 0;
}
```